# Python dictionary with value set to list behaves oddly

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I know `list` object can be changed in place, but `list()` should returns me an independent `list` object each time when it is called. Now I'm confused about the output:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4]
# list() should 
D = dict.fromkeys(L, list())
print(D) # {1: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: []}
D[1].append(1989)
print(D) # {1: [1989], 2: [1989], 3: [1989], 4: [1989]}
```

the required output should be:

```
{1: [1989], 2: [], 3: [], 4: []}
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys

Comment: Using python 3: `D = {x:[] for x in L}`

Comment: `list()` creates *one* list object which is referenced by all keys.

Comment: You are using the same object/list  for all the keys

Comment: @vaultah, why is the downvote? your link doesn't solve my issue. it doesn't explain my concern

Comment: @O'Skywalker Did you read the documentation for `dict.fromkeys`? My bad, the link to tutorial might have worked better.

Comment: nope, I'm learning Python using 'Learning Python, 5th Edition', it says list() will create a new list each time. I ignore dict.fromkeys, could you cancel your downvote? I'll read that book carefully again

Comment: @O'Skywalker Each time it is called, yes, but when it is called only once, it will create only one new list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the `fromkeys` constructor reuses the same value for each key. Thus `list()` is evaluated only once.

You can use either a dict-comprehension:

```
D = {x:list() for x in L}
```

or, if you know that you will always be using lists in your dictionary, use the [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) factory:

```
from collections import defaultdict

D = defaultdict(list)
D[1].append(1989)
D[2].append(2001)

print(D) # {1: [1989], 2: [2001]}
```

Answer (score 2):

`list()` is called once, and that same `list` is used as the value for all keys.

Console transcript (you can see the same `id` for all values):

```
>>> dict.fromkeys(['a', 'b', 'c'])
{'a': None, 'c': None, 'b': None}
>>> dict.fromkeys(['a', 'b', 'c'], 5)
{'a': 5, 'c': 5, 'b': 5}
>>> dict.fromkeys(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2])
{'a': [1, 2], 'c': [1, 2], 'b': [1, 2]}
>>> dict.fromkeys(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3])
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3]}
>>> d = dict.fromkeys(['a', 'b', 'c'], list())
{'a': [], 'c': [], 'b': []}
>>> for key in d: print id(d[key])
... 
4325657272
4325657272
4325657272
```

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using a `defaultdict` from `collections`, it might be more suitable, and at the least it is worth learning about.

```
import collections
D = collections.defaultdict(list)

D[1].append(1989)
D[1].append(1990)

print D[1]
print D
print D[2]
print D
```

This would print the following:

```
[1989, 1990]
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [1989, 1990]})
[]
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [1989, 1990], 2: []})
```

Answer (score 1):

`list()` is only called once. For older version of Python you can use the fact that you can initialise a dict from a list of key/value pairs:

```
D = dict([(x, list()) for x in L]
```

Starting with Python 2.5 you can use generators and leave out the list construction from the previous example:

```
D = dict((x, list()) for x in L)
```

Starting with python 2.7 and 3.0 you can use the, initially rejected for python 2.3, dict comprehension from [PEP 274](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
D = {x: list() for x in L}
```

Comment: I had inadvertently copied in that line from my test code instead of the dict comprehension.